# How to hide Linear layout when ListView data is empty?

Tags: android, listview

I want to hide whole Linear layout when listview is empty?
I tried setEmptyView but that thing i dont needed.

Here my listView code :-

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_notification_task, container, false);
    listschedule=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.notificationtaskschedule);
    LinearLayout schduletasks=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.sch);
     new pendingscheduletask().execute();
         return view;
}
//daily task pending
private class pendingdailytask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        try {
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", suid));
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_psendingdailytask, "GET", params);

            int success1 = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("success4"));
            Log.d("success4", json.toString());
            if (success1 == 0) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Not Data Found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (success1 == 1) {
                ownerObj = json.getJSONArray("daily");
                for (int i = 0; i < ownerObj.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = ownerObj.getJSONObject(i);

                    daily_task_name.add(jsonobject.getString("t_tname"));
                    daily_task_time.add(jsonobject.getString("t_time"));
                    daily_task_detail.add(jsonobject.getString("t_detail"));
                    daily_task_id.add(jsonobject.getString("t_id"));
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        listadapter = new ListViewAdapterPendingdailytask(getActivity(), daily_task_name,daily_task_time,daily_task_detail,daily_task_id);
        listdaily.setAdapter(listadapter);

        Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listdaily);
    }
}
public static class Utility {
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

here the above code is for listview when the data is empty i want to hide Linear Layout. i don't know how to perform this task. i tried a lot but not getting the excet output.

i Tried setEmptyView in this i can put a textview when the listview is empty. but i want to hide whole linear layout.

Comment: Is it `schduletasks.setVisibility(View.GONE)` that you are missing?

Comment: where did i put this??

Comment: like i tried this on f (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }  under this but not working on this

Comment: Well, wherever/whenever you want to hide the `LinearLayout`. Probably in the `onPostExecute()` if `daily_task_name.size() == 0` (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are setting your `ListView` height based in all it's children height, why don't you just set its height to `wrap_content`?

To Achieve what you want you just need to do this in `onPostExecute`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    //in this if clause make your logic between OR/AND depending on what you want
    if(daily_task_name.size() != 0 || daily_task_time.size != 0 || ....){ 
        listadapter = new ListViewAdapterPendingdailytask(getActivity(), daily_task_name,daily_task_time,daily_task_detail,daily_task_id);
        listdaily.setAdapter(listadapter);
        Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listdaily);
    } else{
        //assuming this is the LinearLayout you want to be gone
        schduletasks.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout schduletasks;
```

...

```
 @Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_notification_task, container, false);
listschedule=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.notificationtaskschedule);
schduletasks=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.sch);
 new pendingscheduletask().execute();
     return view;
```

}

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    listadapter = new ListViewAdapterPendingdailytask(getActivity(), daily_task_name,daily_task_time,daily_task_detail,daily_task_id);
    listdaily.setAdapter(listadapter);
    if(listAdapter == null) {

        schduletasks.setVisibility(View.Gone);

       } else{



    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listdaily);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listdaily.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listdaily.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listdaily.setLayoutParams(params); 

       }

}
```

Comment: how can we directly setVisibility(gone) in the postexecute??

Comment: yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: onPostExecute runs on Ui thread,, that's why we can change visibility from that method

Comment: Don't you mean instance variable instead of global variable?

Comment: I mean that your layout must be defined

Comment: I hope it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

I picture this as the following: [image]

Since you are loading your data from a [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you post loading operation can be done in the method `onPostExecute` which you already implemented the only thing that you need to do is to call `setVisibility(GONE)` for a specific view.

```
linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Now your condition to wether or not the adapter is empty since to be depending on a multiple on `daily_task_detail` you can use the method size to figure out wether or not your adapter will have data.

**Side note:**

- I usually have an adapter set in the onCreate (Activity) or onActivityCreated(Fragment), but very first in the lifecycle, and the then just modify the items in the adapter with a method that ensure it'll call [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) or [notifyDataSetInvalidated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated())
- Do not call any UI based method like `Snackbar.make(view, "Not Data Found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in the onBackground method, without posting it to the main thread.
- You might know tihs but AsyncTask have been come down in favour of other [alternatives](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/9), IntentServices, RxAndroid, Sync.